# Proofs from the BOOK: Bertrand's postulate: $\binom{2m+1}{m}\leq 2^{2m}$

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I have a very hard proof from "Proofs from the BOOK". It's the section about Bertrand's postulate, [page 8](http://books.google.com/books?id=CuTpgZaLahkC&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q&f=false):

It's about the part, where the author says:

$$\binom{2m+1}{m}\leq 2^{2m}$$
because $\binom{2m+1}{m}=\binom{2m+1}{m+1}$ are the same in $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{2m+1} \binom{2m+1}{k}=2^{2m+1}$

I see, why they are the same, but I don't see the reason to say $\binom{2m+1}{m}\leq 2^{2m}$. Any help would be fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum is essentially $a_1 + a_2 + ... +a_m + a_{m+1} + ... + a_{2m+1} = 2^{2m+1}$, (where $a_k$ is shorthand for $\binom{2m+1}{k}$) since everything is non-negative, we can say $a_m + a_{m+1} \leq  a_1 + a_2 + ... +a_m + a_{m+1} + ... + a_{2m+1} = 2^{2m+1}$ and from the equality we know $a_m = a_{m+1}$. Putting it all together:

$a_m + a_{m+1} = 2a_m \leq 2^{2m+1}$ therefore $a_m \leq 2^{2m}$

Answer (score 5):

$\binom{2m+1}{m}+\binom{2m+1}{m+1}\leq 2^{2m+1}$ (follows from binomial formula)

But the coefficients are the same, so

$2\binom{2m+1}{m}\leq 2^{2m+1}$

Answer (score 2):

Since $2m+1$ is odd, there will be an even number of coefficients (since you have everything from $\binom{2m+1}{0}$ to $\binom{2m+1}{2m+1}$). Because the coefficients are symmetric, you can write:

$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2m+1}{k}=\sum \limits_{k=m+1}^{2m+1} \binom{2m+1}{k}$

But $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{2m+1} \binom{2m+1}{k}=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2m+1}{k} + \sum \limits_{k=m+1}^{2m+1} \binom{2m+1}{k}=2^{2m+1}$

$2 \times \sum \limits_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2m+1}{k} = 2^{2m+1}$

$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2m+1}{k} = 2^{2m}$

Since $\binom{2m+1}{m}$ is part of the sum $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2m+1}{k}$, it follows that $\binom{2m+1}{m}\leq 2^{2m}$, equality when $m=0$

Comment: and when m is not 0?

Comment: Then $\binom{2m+1}{m} < 2^{2m}$